# How to print a matrix using Python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a matrix and then print it using python with the following expected output:

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

The code follows:

```
    matrix=[[]]
    matrix = [[0 for x in range(4)] for x in range(4)]
    print matrix
```

But the output comes as:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Please tell me why I'm getting this type of output and help with the correct one

Comment: This code does not yield this output.

Comment: yes, the output for this code is: [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]

Comment: he just replicated it 4 times

Comment: It sounds like you've placed code inside a loop that belongs outside the loop.

Comment: Thank you guys...it was helpful.

Answer (score 5):

What you are getting is the correct representation of a matrix.  You have created a list that contains 4 lists, each list containing 4 '0's.  If you want to print it differently then you have some options, but what you are printing is the representation of the above mentioned data structure.

```
for row in matrix:
  print ' '.join(map(str,row))
```

this should work for you.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
matrix = "\n".join([" ".join(["0" for x in range(4)]) for x in range(4)])
print matrix
```

The thing is that you're trying to print a list object instead of a string. This way you join all of the numbers into 1 large string separated with spaces for columns and \n (line endings) for rows.

Keep in mind this method will not work for 2 digit numbers unless you pad the 1 digit with a leading zero or space. In order for it to work in all cases, I suggest using the [Tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) module.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
matrix=[[]]
matrix = [[0 for x in range(4)] for x in range(4)]
for a in matrix:
    ln = ""
    for i in a:
        ln += str(i) + " "
    print(ln)
```